# Can't measure bmi in object with external function

Tags: javascript, function, object

tried to measure the bmi of john in an object with external function
but it didn't work.

```js
function bmiCalc(objName) {
  objName.bmi = objName.mass / (objName.height * objName.height);
}

var john = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Miller',
  mass: 85,
  height: 1.69,
  bmiCalc: bmiCalc(this)
};

console.log(john);
```

Comment: `this` does not refer to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` does not refer to the object you are creating with that literal. Furthermore, your function does not return anything, but performs an assignment.

Several ways exist to make it work. This is one of them:

```js
function bmiCalc(objName) {
  objName.bmi = objName.mass / (objName.height * objName.height);
}

var john = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Miller',
  mass: 85,
  height: 1.69,
};
bmiCalc(john);

console.log(john);
```

#### Using prototype/class

The more natural way to do this, is to create a constructor and -- why not -- using the `class` syntax. Make `bmi` a getter, so that even when someone's weight or height changes, the BMI adapts accordingly:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, mass, height) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.height = height;
    }
    get bmi() {
        return this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
    }
}

var john = new Person('John', 'Miller', 83, 1.69);
john.weight = 85; // He gained two kilo since last measure.
console.log(john.bmi);
```

Comment: thank you so much now it all makes sense.
I'm just a beginner and got confused.